# How to edit check/uncheck of input

Tags: jquery, edit, element

- If user click to span with text First, it should mark off checkbox #First etc.
- If user again click to this span, it should uncheck this checkbox
- If is checked input Second, span with text second must have class active

How can I do that?

```
$("span").on("click", function() {
    $("input").prop( "checked", true );
});
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdeWPx)

Comment: What's wrong with using a `label`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing in your codepen is on the right track.

However, you need to do the same thing both ways. i.e. on span click, change the checkbox state; and also on checkbox change, toggle the span class.

Also, remember that while using `.eq($(this).index()..` do not forget to pass the selector. Otherwise, it will get the index of that element in relation to the siblings.

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/r8w38jr5/2/**

**Snippet:**

```js
$("span.lbl").on("click", function() {
    var inp = $("input[type=checkbox]").eq($(this).index('.lbl')), 
        chk = inp.prop('checked');
    inp.prop("checked", !chk);
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    var spn = $("span.lbl").eq($(this).index('[type=checkbox]')); 
    spn.toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
span {
    padding: 5px 10px; display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div  { margin-top: 50px; }
.active { background: black; color: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="lbl">First</span><span class="lbl">Second</span><span class="lbl">Third</span>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="First" /><label for="First">First</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Second" /><label for="Second">Second</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Third" /><label for="Third">Third</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select `input` using index

```
$("span").on("click", function() {
    $("input").eq($(this).index()).prop( "checked", true );
});
```

**NOTE :** In order to prevent selecting all span set some class and use it as selector.

Comment: That's the idea but the page can contain many more spans and inputs